# Django query to select parent with nonzero children

Tags: django, hierarchical-data, django-queryset

I have model with a Foreign Key to itself like this:

```
class Concept(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category = models.ForeignKey('self')
```

But I can't figure out how I can select all concepts that have nonzero children value. Is this possible with django QuerySet API or I must write custom SQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, each `Concept` may have another `Concept` as parent, and this is set into the `category` field.
In other words, a `Concept` with at least a child will be referenced at least once in the `category` field.

Generally speaking, this is not really easy to get in Django; however if you do not have too many categories, you can think for a query of the like of `SELECT * FROM CONCEPTS WHERE CONCEPTS.ID IN (SELECT CATEGORY FROM CONCEPTS);` - and this is something you can map easily with Django:

```
Concept.objects.filter(pk__in=Concept.objects.all().values('category'))
```

Note that, as stated on [Django documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in), this query may have performance issues on certain databases; therefore you should instead put it as a list:

```
Concept.objects.filter(id__in=list(Concept.objects.all().values('category')))
```

But please be aware that this could hit some database limitation -- for instance, Oracle allows up to 1000 elements in such lists.

Comment: Thank you for deep explanation!

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this:

```
concepts = Concept.objects.exclude(category=None)
```

Comment: but category is not None for concepts with no children, your query will give uncategorized concepts (concept and category are essentially the same entities)

Answer (score 3):

The way you have it written there will require a value for `category`. Once you have fixed that (with `null=True` in the field constructor), use this:

```
Concept.objects.filter(category__isnull=False)
```